# Добавление google аккаунт

Tags: android, auth, oauth, google-account

Необходимо связать приложения с аккаунтом google для восстановления настроек при переходе на другое устройство. Подскажите что почитать или ссылку на пример, в идеале.

Comment: Посмотрите https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup в этом направлении?

Comment: @SergeMarkov да спасибо, похоже оно